# property access must assign to the property or use it value vb

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I get this error, "property access must assign to the property or use its value" I am trying to assign values in a texbox and a combobox to a single vaiable but it gives an error. My line of assignment is `feditForm.textbox.Text & "-" & feditForm.comboBox.Text = fnum`.   `fnum` is the variable which holds the value got from the datagridview cell. it is defined as `Dim fnum As String = Me.regFarmGrd.SelectedRows(0).Cells("NUMBER").Value`. What might be wrong?

Comment: Your "line of assignment" makes no sense to me - can you show an actual snippet of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Based on guesswork, try:

```
fnum = feditForm.textbox.Text & "-" & feditForm.comboBox.Text
```